# Cannot convert value of type 'Int.Type' to expected argument type 'Int"

Tags: swift

I am trying to call a function in an if statement, but I always get the error message "Cannot convert value of type 'Int.Type' to expected argument type 'Int". What am I doing wrong?

```
func isLeapYear(year: Int) -> Bool {

    if year % 4 != 0{
        return false
    }
    else if year % 100 != 0{
        return true
    }
    else if year % 400 != 0{
        return false
    }
    else{
        return true
    }
}

func nextDay(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) -> (year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {

    if isLeapYear(year: Int) == true {
        if day < daysOfMonths_leap[month-1] {
            return ( year, month, day + 1 ) 
        }else {
            if month == 12 {
                return (year + 1, 1, 1)
            } else {
               return (year, month + 1, 1)
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to read ["Defining and Calling Functions"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID159) again ... `isLeapYear(year: Int)` is *not* how you *call* the function for a given year.

Comment: You have to pass an actual value as an argument not the type. Please try ...if isLeapYear(year: year) == true

Comment: Why do you reinvent the wheel? The classes `Calender` and `DateComponents` provide all kinds of date math.

Comment: @NMM you could simplify your function conditions in just one line as follow: `return (year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0) || year % 400 == 0`

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling a function, you should enter its value

```
if isLeapYear(year: year) == true {
```

or

```
if isLeapYear(year: Int(1)) == true {
```

Comment: `== true` is redundant. isLeapYear returns a Bool

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the value of the parameter to the function instead the type of the parameter.

Here I considered that you need to use a parameter of nextDay function.

When you call a function which have parameters you need to provide a value to the function parameter because this value will be use inside the function. Value type should be same as the parameter type. In this case Int.

Try this:

```
func isLeapYear(year: Int) -> Bool {

    if year % 4 != 0{
        return false
    }
    else if year % 100 != 0{
        return true
    }
    else if year % 400 != 0{
        return false
    }
    else{
        return true
    }
}

func nextDay(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) -> (year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {

    // Your function call
    if isLeapYear(year: year) == true {
        // Your code
    }

    // Hardcorded values (year 2, month 2, days 2)
        return (2, 2, 2)
    }
```

Comment: First copy and paste the code in playground and check the output. then develop the code by with your code. If get an error paste here.